# How to extract encoded transport stream frames from a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, video-capture, mpeg

Searching for a method to extract from video stream (.m2t or .ts file) a certain frames as is, encoded. OpenCV also extracts frames easily but decodes them immediately.
Given:

- A .ts or .m2t file with H.264/MPEG-4 encoded stream.
- Starting point in time for extraction like h:m:s.f (example: 0:2:1.12).
- Ending point in time in the same format.

I need to read from the file all frames in the given interval and provide to another program as buffer frame by frame as they are. The catch here is to keep the frames encoded as they are, do not decode/encode/encapsulate them.

Picking a frame from the H.264 m2t to a pipe:

`ffmpeg -ss 0:2:1.12 -i .\my_video.ts -c:v copy -f mpegts -frames:v 1 pipe: -y -hide_banner`

Obviously, the time stamp is increasing for every next frame. From the pipe it is not a problem to convert it to a buffer.

Questions:

1. Is this method correct to extract a separate frame as it is without
   any reference/recalculations with neighbor frames?
2. Not sure that flag `-f mpegts` really keeps the frame untouched. Is there better flag? (Maybe `-f null`?)
3. How to know the type of extracted frame (i, P, or B)?

Thank you.

Comment: You may check my [code in GitHub](https://github.com/cohenrotem/pipe_flv2annexb/blob/master/pipe_flv2annexb.py). I choose FLV video container (mpegts seem to complicated for "manual" parsing).

Comment: Thank you @Rotem, good stuff to learn. I wonder if there are similar to `+no_sequence_end+no_metadata+no_duration_filesize` flags for .m2t or .ts streams.

Comment: Indeed, FLV seems simpler than TS. However, it's not my decision. I have to keep the TS format encoded. In addition to `-f mpegts` tried to use `-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb`. No luck. I wonder why the frames are changed while they should be copied by `copy` codec?

Comment: You may start from something simple and reproducible. Example: **1.** Build synthetic TS file using FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=10:duration=10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p in.ts` **2.** "re-mux" the TS file to another TS file: `ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -vcodec copy -f mpegts out.ts` **3.** Verify that `in.ts` and `out.ts` are identical.

Comment: For verifying that the PIPE is not the issue try: `ffmpeg -i in.ts -vcodec copy -f mpegts pipe: > out2.ts`  Verify that `in.ts` and `out2.ts` are identical.

Comment: Great idea, Rotem, Thanks! The full copy of the synthetic TS works perfect straight to the file and via the pipe. adding `-ss a:b:c.d` before or after the `-i` input stream results with 0 byte output. No errors reported thus. Interesting that adding `-frames:v N` works fine and takes neede number of frames to the output, starting from 0. Only `-ss` flag makes all the trouble here. Is there other method to indicate start position to the `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I think the issue is related to keyframes. I am not sure how the seeking mechanism works, but a valid output steam must start with a keyframe. The input seeking (in TS file) is probably looking for the nearest keyframe after the seeking position. For testing, try making all the input frames to be keyframes (add `-g 1`): `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=10:duration=10 -g 1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p in.ts`

Comment: Thanks for your grit! So far the results are: the "base" command is `ffmpeg.exe -y -i c:\\temp\\<type>_in.ts -ss 0:%s:%s.%s -vcodec copy -f mpegts -frames:v 1 pipe: -hide_banner >> c:\\temp\\stream_%s.ts`. For regular <type> of input the result is none. For all-i-frames the result is a big file. In that big file the difference starts from second frame (seen in hex editor). Only 1st frame in that big file plays (makes sense).

Comment: If the  "base" command is changed to `ffmpeg.exe -y -i c:\\temp\\<type>_in.ts -ss 0:%s:%s.%s -copyts -f mpegts -frames:v 1 pipe: -hide_banner >> c:\\temp\\stream_%s.ts` then both regular and all-i-frame inputs produce huge and not playing output. The difference with the original starts in the 1st frame. Interesting that `-vcodec copy` base produces good video from all-i-frame input if `-frames:v` > 1. Seems plain concatenation to the output of pipe also impacts the result.

Comment: Note: I didn't say all I-Frames is a good idea, I just suggested to test it (checking if the problem is related to the key frames or not)...

Comment: Sure, that's clear :) Thanks to your experiment I understand that there is not a problem with frame extraction. There is a problem with connecting frames back to the stream... Unless, my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile, I managed to "reconstruct" a part of input stream by concatenating chunks of the trim filter. `ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -vf trim=1.5:2 -f mpegts pipe: -hide_banner >> result02.mp4` where `trim` values are increasing with every run. 
This is not perfect approach because the stream is being re-encoded for every chunk. But it is good enough to keep sequential times, order, and smooth play of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer slightly diverts the original question. However, it does the job and gives good enough result.

The original question requested to extract encoded video frame by frame. Suggested variants extract to the standar output a compressed videos in batches of several frames. This is easy to pick in software and process/concatenate later as needed.

### Variant 1

This method gives **really** smooth video by concatenation of resulting chunks.  This method consumes more CPU than the Variant 2. And processing of every next chunk in the movie takes longer and longer. Therefore, Variant 2 is way better in terms of performance.

`ffmpeg.exe -y -nostdin -loglevel quiet -hide_banner -i "c:\\temp\\in.ts" -vf trim=<from_second>:<to_second> -f mpegts pipe:`

The order of keys is important and means:

- `-y -nostdin -loglevel quiet -hide_banner` - don't ask questions, don't print  excessive output.
- `-vf x:y` - videofilter which trims out all the movie except the part between start and stop position of required video chunk from original file. These are floats.
- `-f mpegts` - normally not needed if the output goes to the file: ffmpeg knows to derive format from the file name. In this case the result goes to the pipe to explicit specification of the output format needed.

### Variant 2

This method gives *almost* smooth video by concatenation of resulting chunks. *Almost* good is visible jumping video, so it is not perfect method in terms of quality.

`ffmpeg.exe -y -nostdin -loglevel quiet -hide_banner -ss <from_second> -t <chunk_duration> -i "c:\\temp\\in.ts" -copyts -f mpegts pipe:`

Not repeating the explained options in the variant 1, only new options:

- `-ss <from_second>` - skip the movie until specified position. It is important to give this key BEFORE the `-i` to save processing time. Else the ffmpeg will read all the movie until specified position, not skipping it. This can be supplied in format `h:mm:ss.ff` or just float seconds.
- `-t <chunk_duration>` - required/optimal chunk size. This is float. If the GOP is known it's better to take chunks by the GOP size. This improves performance.
- `-copyts` - keep the timestamps of video chunks from the original video. Without this key the result will play only forst frame of each chunk. Better interpretation/understanding is welcome.